# Setting color not displayed in editor in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to customize the color of HTML tags in react (.tsx files). So, I included the code below in `settings.json` file.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {    
    "textMateRules": [
      // TextMate grammars tokenization settings
      {
        "name": "JSX tags",
        "scope": [
          "entity.name.tag", // HTML tags (in JSX)
          "entity.name.tag.html", // JSX Component tags
          "meta.tag",
          "meta.jsx"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#18da32"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

However, even after the settings is applied, the color does not change (the color should be like so [image])

What is being displayed

[image]

However, when I use the developer tools it shows the right Hex code!
[image]

The other tag is displayed correctly (the dark orange color)
[image]

Is this some kind of bug or am i doing something wrong? I even closed VS code & started again but no use.

Comment: I raised this issue with VScode on Github & got the response which resolved the issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138569

Answer (score 0):

your `settings.json` is not a valid json it is missing outer curly braces.

```
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {    
    "textMateRules": [
      // TextMate grammars tokenization settings
      {
        "name": "JSX tags",
        "scope": [
          "entity.name.tag", // HTML tags (in JSX)
          "entity.name.tag.html", // JSX Component tags
          "meta.tag",
          "meta.jsx"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#18da32"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The settings are valid, else the foreground color that i set would not show in the developer view. When I copied the code to post the question, I may have missed the outer curly braces.